# Postgres : Truncate if exists in psql function with parameter

Tags: postgresql, functions

I am trying to get a psql function that would truncate a given table name if it exists. I've been trying multiple functions, but none of them worked so far. Here is the code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION truncateIfExists(tableName TEXT)
returns void
as $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format(
'IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_name =' || tableName || '
    )
THEN
TRUNCATE tableName;
END IF;
');
END;
$$language plpgsql
```

Now, I am able to get it to work in a simple procedure with a harcoded name :

```
do $$
begin
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
 FROM information_schema.tables 
 WHERE table_name = genre_epf)
 THEN
 TRUNCATE genre_epf;
END IF;
end
$$;
```

But I can't wrap my head on how to mix both queries. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: The problem is the `TRUNCATE tableName;`. You are trying to truncate a table named `tableName`,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [the variable FOUND](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#plpgsql-statements-diagnostics):

```
create or replace function truncate_if_exists(tablename text)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
    perform 1
    from information_schema.tables 
    where table_name = tablename;
    if found then
        execute format('truncate %I', tablename);
    end if;
end $$;
```

Note that I've used `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT` as I don't need an output of the query. I want to know whether the query returns any row (`FOUND = true`) or not (`FOUND = false`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is the underscore naming a Postgres convention ?

Comment: It's possible to use "camelCaseIdentifiers" but they must be enclosed in double-quotes to be really case-sensitive. Hence identifiers_with_underscores is a convention preferred by many advanced Postgres users. Read about identifiers [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#sql-syntax-identifiers)